# Automatically launch a localhost to open an offline HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, localhost

In my project folder, I have a "project.html" and a "project.JS" file.
I do not want to let the user launch the program by opening the "project.html" file. Instead of that, I want them access by localhost (e.g. localhost:8080).

I want to create a file "launch.html" that when the user opens it, they will automatically launch a server that hosts the "project.html" file. After that, when the user access localhost:8080, they will automatically see the "project.html".

How to do that? It should be an HTML file to launch the localhost and it would be better if the user don't have to install anything else like Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for an HTML document to cause a web browser to run an arbitrary application (including an HTTP server).

You tagged this question [electron](/questions/tagged/electron). Your needs (to treat this as an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) will probably be better served by distributing an electron application instead of an HTML document.